# Lookup for data in table 2 and display it in table1

Tags: sql, oracle11g

As you can see the  expected output below, whenever the column names & the value of table1 matches with COLNAME & ODS OF Table2 then we should display corresponding extract value of Table2 in place of original value in Table1

```
Table1 Data

B_T      |   S_T     |  other columns

1        |    3      | -----

2        |    2      | -----

3        |    7      | -----
```

Table2 Data

```
COLNAME  |   ODS     |  EXTRACT

B_T      |    1      | 100

S_T      |    2      | 200

B_T      |    2      | 200
```

Please help me to write SELECT statement to get the following output in Oracle11g

Expected Output:

```
B_T      |   S_T     |  other columns

100      |    3      | -----

200      |    200    | -----

3        |    7      | -----
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. try this .

```
select t2.extract as b_T,t1.S_t,<other columns>
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on  t1.s_t = t2.ods
```

Comment: Thanks Raj, but we cannot join on t1.b_t = t2.colname as t1.b_t returns values like 1,2,3 and not column name, so the above query does not work.

Comment: True..I got messed up with your table data. So reformatted it. It should work now.